# How to get the URL of the entity reference node?

Tags: entities, uri, views

I'm building a site of course video，one course includes many video clips. I have created 2 content types, one is for the **Course** ,and the other is for the **Video**.

In the *course* content type, I set a field of entity reference to make a relation between course and video.

And then I create a view to display the video list on the video node page, it works. I wonder how can I add the link of the relative course node page on this video node page, how can I get the URL of the entity referenced course node page?

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use views "realationships" to achieve that

Comment: Would you like to provide a example?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late answer, but hopefully it will help others looking to get the raw URLs for related content (especially if you're building a custom theme file for the view).

In the view:

1. Under "Relationships", add a `Entity Reference: Referenced Entity` relationship for the related field.
2. Under "Fields", add a `Content: Path` field
3. Set that field to use the relationship.
4. In the field settings, deselect label; under style settings, set the wrapper HTML to none.
5. Under "Rewrite Results", select "Rewrite the output of this field"
6. Use the replacement patterns to add just the `[path]` token. If you already have a separate Path field selected in the view, it may show up as `[path_1]` or a similar name.
7. Save & test the view.

Answer (score 0):

> **Views Relationships** : Relationships are used to allow Views to bring in data that is associated with the data already available in
>   the view.

**References**

- [Using Views with the Entity Reference module in Drupal 7](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/using-views-entity-reference-module-drupal-7)
- [Using View's Relationships](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-views-relationships)
- [Using Relation with Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/1276380)
- [USING VIEWS RELATIONSHIPS, ARGUMENTS, AND ATTACHMENTS](http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2009/07/using-views-relationships-arguments-attachments)